# Can get templateInstance value but can't use it for another function?

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

I just recently figured out how to get the id of an element from one of my template instances and am trying to use it in another function, but although the console log returns the correct IDs, when I try to use them, like in my `.play()` function, it says that "undefined is not a function". This occurs no matter what function I try to do, be it eventlistener, or anything! I figured that the problem was something to do with how javascript sees elements in the shadowDOM maybe? I'm not entirely sure. Here's my function:

```
//plays an audio file by it's id specified in a repeating template
playAudio: function () {
    var audioId = event.target.templateInstance.model.s.soundId;
    console.log(audioId);
    //^ that is correct in the console log for every ID
    var image = event.target.templateInstance.model.s.imgId;
    console.log(image);
    //^ further tests, this is correct for every img ID
    audioId.play();
    //"undefined is not a function"
}
```

and then my repeating template, which has the `on-click:{{playAudio}}` on the img element.

```
<template>
    <div layout horizontal wrap center center-justified class="asdf">
        <template repeat="{{s in carddata}}">
            <sound-card>
                <img src="{{s.imgurl}}" id="{{s.imgId}}" on-click="{{playAudio}}">
                <span>{{s.quote}}</span>
                <audio id="{{s.soundId}}" src="{{s.soundurl}}" controls preload="auto"></audio>
            </sound-card>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

Is there something I'm missing in regards to how javascript handles elements that I got from a repeating template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't play a string. Instead, you'll need to get the actual DOM element first, like so:

```
document.getElementById(audioId).play();
```